# How to resolve arithmetic syntax error in printf

Tags: linux, sunos

I am running below code in `SunOS` as `.sh` file

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#lerning linux scripting 
#
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4s\n" No Name Mark 
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4.2f\n" 1 James 80.1234
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4.2f\n" 2 Sarah 99.8923
```

But I am getting below **error** when run above one in `SunOS`

```
No    Name       Mark

: arithmetic syntax error.sh[5]: printf: 80.1234
: arithmetic syntax error0.1234
linux_sc.sh[5]: printf: warning: invalid argument of type f
80.12
: arithmetic syntax error.sh[6]: printf: 99.8923
: arithmetic syntax error9.8923
linux_sc.sh[6]: printf: warning: invalid argument of type f
99.89
```

Comment: Why is there nothing in front of `:` in the error message? Did you remove anything from the error message? Please edit your post (with the edit button on the left side below your post) and prepend the error message with 4 spaces - to make it look like the script, in code-like block, and preserve newlines. Can you try with `/usr/bin/printf` or `/bin/printf` instead of `printf`?

Comment: Added full response

Comment: Does your file perhaps have Windows-style line endings instead of Unix ones? If the version of cat on SunOS/Solaris supports it, try `cat -t your.sh` to see if there's a `^M` at the end of each line. (Or see if `file your.sh` reports CRLF line terminators)

Comment: That would make sense, why is there nothing in front of `:`, the `\r` somewhere overwrites the beginning of the line.

Comment: I tried cat -t my.sh file and there is non ^M at the end of line , response show as below #!/usr/bin/sh
#lerning linux scripting
#
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4s\n" No Name Mark
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4.2f\n" 1 James 80.1234
printf "%-5s %-10s %-4.2f\n" 2 Sarah 99.8923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, pretty sure you're using a script that has Windows style CRLF line endings, while Unix systems use LF. This happens when you write the file on Windows and don't transfer it to the other computer in a way that translates line endings.

Taking your sample script and running it through `unix2dos` and then trying to run it gives:

```
No    Name       Mark

: invalid numberprintf: 80.1234
1     James      0.00
: invalid numberprintf: 99.8923
2     Sarah      0.00
```

Not exactly the same output, but I'm testing on Linux, not SunOS, so that's to be expected. Close enough, though, to suggest it's the issue.

If you have `dos2unix` installed on the SunOS box, run your script through it and see if that fixes the problem. Or `perl -pi -e 's/\r//' your.sh` is another way of stripping the extraneous carriage returns. Or `tr -d '\r' < your.sh > new.sh` or any number of other ways; just depends on what a typical SunOS setup has installed. I haven't used it in years; don't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Perhaps also try adding a trailing space after the numbers?